# Get Wikipedia page links without template links

Tags: wikipedia-api

When querying the Wikipedia API for page links it returns all the page links and additionally the links inside of templates rendered into that page.

An example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Mahatma_Gandhi

returns `10 Janpath`, which is not linked in the page but only in a template.

Is it possible to only get the page's links via the API directly or do I have to parse the (wiki)text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do that directly using the API. [MediaWiki stores link information for each page as a whole](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Links_table), it does not differentiate between links from the page itself and from templates used in the page.

So parsing the page wikitext is your best option.

Comment: How can we get the list of all links available in the 'See Also' section?